# Centos7 - upgrading mysql 5.6 to mysql community 8

Tags: mysql, centos7

I'm trying to upgrade mysql community 5.6 to mysql community 8.

I have ran:

```
rpm -Uvh https://repo.mysql.com/mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch.rpm
```

and I get back:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    mysql-community-release conflicts with mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch
```

Yum repostlist enabled | grep "mysql" shows:

```
 mysql-connectors-community/x86_64 MySQL Connectors Community                  51
mysql-tools-community/x86_64      MySQL Tools Community                       63
mysql56-community/x86_64          MySQL 5.6 Community Server                 395
```

how can I update mysql to the latest mysql community release?

thanks

Comment: Remove the conflicting package.

Comment: I have mysql 5.6 installed and I cannot uninstall it.  I guess I would have to backup all of the DBs, remove msyql, reinstall?  no way to 'upgrade'?